# Manage independent script component architecture in unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

I have different set of objects where I have to show **Name UI** and **Menu UI** using `OnMouseDown` and on `OnMouseEnter` Events. Remember Both are optional, the one object may contain(attach) both option(script) or maybe one option(script).

Currently I have manage to write two separate scripts like this, that include `input` + `action`:

*For  Menu UI Handling :*

```
     /// <summary>
    /// It will shown the three button menu on mouse click.
    /// </summary>
    public class DisplayMenu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject canvasMenuNavigation;
        public Image panelNavigation;
        public float machineNameYPosition = 0f;

        [SerializeField]
        BtnFurtherExplosionAnimationDeactive btnFurtherExplosionAnimationDeactive;

        public void Reset()
        {

            canvasMenuNavigation                    = GameObject.Find("Canvas_MenuNavigation");
            panelNavigation                         = canvasMenuNavigation.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
            btnFurtherExplosionAnimationDeactive    = canvasMenuNavigation.GetComponentInChildren<BtnFurtherExplosionAnimationDeactive>();

        }

        private void OnMouseDown()
        {
            if (AnimationStateManager.currentAnimationState != AnimationStates.None)
            {
                Debug.Log("onmousedown");
                DisplayMenueCanvas(true);

                panelNavigation.transform.position = new Vector3(
                    this.transform.position.x,
                    this.transform.position.y + machineNameYPosition,
                    this.transform.position.z);


                string currentAnimatioType = this.name.Split('_')[3];
                Debug.Log(currentAnimatioType);

                AnimationStates selectedState = (AnimationStates)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimationStates), currentAnimatioType, true);
                FindObjectOfType<SelectedAnimationType>().selectedAnimationType = selectedState;

                btnFurtherExplosionAnimationDeactive.ButtonActive();
            }

        }


        void DisplayMenueCanvas(bool isActive)
        {
            canvasMenuNavigation.SetActive(isActive);
        }
    }
```

*AND The below script will mange to show `Name UI`:*

```
/// <summary>
/// Display Name UI on mouse Enter event and hide on mouse exit
/// </summary>
public class DisplayMachinePartNameOnMouseOver : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject   machinePartNameShow;
    public Canvas       partNameCavnas;
    public Image        partNameImage;
    public LineDrawer   lineDrawer;
    public Text         txtMachinePartName;
    public float        machineNameYPosition = 5f;

    public void Reset()
    {

        machinePartNameShow = GameObject.Find("MachinePartNameShow");
        partNameCavnas      = machinePartNameShow.GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>();
        partNameImage       = machinePartNameShow.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
        lineDrawer          = machinePartNameShow.GetComponentInChildren<LineDrawer>();
        txtMachinePartName  = machinePartNameShow.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();

    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
            //Position the UI
            partNameImage.transform.position = new Vector3(
            this.transform.position.x,
            this.transform.position.y + machineNameYPosition,
            this.transform.position.z);

            //Set line between Name and Object
            lineDrawer.SetLine(this.transform.position, partNameImage.transform.position);

            //Get the name 
            string machinePartName = MachinePartNames.MachinePartName(this.name);
            Debug.Log(machinePartName);

            if (machinePartName != null)
            {
                //show the name
                txtMachinePartName.text = machinePartName;

                //activate the name UI
                DisplayMachinePartName(true);
            }
        }       
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        //Deactive the part name UI
        DisplayMachinePartName(false);
    }

    void DisplayMachinePartName(bool isActive)
    {
        machinePartNameShow.SetActive(isActive);
    }
}
```

How can I improve this code? So that the input class and other (action) functionality handle separately. As you can see, currently I am doing input and functionality/Action in the same class. I am willing to convert it to independent components scripts. So that I able to apply the SOLID principle.